# Adding list of people liking post in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am making social service in asp.net mvc. I want to make "like" button. I came up to idea that I will make list of people who liked the post in PostModel so I added that line to model.

`public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> WhoLiked { get; set; }`

Maybe it is important that migration builder isnt empty but I couldnt see any changes in database after this migration.

Then I made this method in controller.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Like(int id)
        {
            ApplicationUser model = new ApplicationUser();
            model = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);

            var post = await _db.Posts.FindAsync(id);

            if (post.WhoLiked.Contains(model))
            {
                post.Likes -= 1;
                post.WhoLiked.Remove(model);
            }
            else
            {
                post.Likes += 1;
                post.WhoLiked.Add(model);
            }
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
        }
```

Im getting "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Comment: On which line did you get that error?

Comment: if (post.WhoLiked.Contains(model))

Comment: Now, put a breakpoint on it and find out whether `post`, `WhoLiked` or `model` is null.

Comment: ```WhoLiked``` is null

Comment: Now it's time to find out why `WhoLiked` is null. Go check your database, if the corresponding table exists, check your migrations, etc ...

Comment: The problem is I dont know why it is null. I cant see column ```WhoLiked``` in database like it doesnt exist but I dont know why